# Null value in column "id" during insert in Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot

Structure of table **messages**-

```
id - Integer - NotNull - Primary Key
message - text - NotNull
```

When I tried to insert using

```
INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES ('abc');
```

It gives the following error-

```
ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "messages" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, abc).
SQL state: 23502
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Modify your table such that id is autoincrementing

Comment: @Strawberry That's exactly what I want to know,about how to do it in Postgres.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm

Comment: Add your entity class..ensure that you have field annotated with @Id and generation type stretegy defined.

Comment: Use datatype `serial` instead of integer.

Comment: @Alien yes,I'm using Id and
  GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  ,still not able to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your entity

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

Or
Change id data type to serial in postgres;

```
id - serial-Primary Key
message - text - NotNull
```

something like:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    id  SERIAL NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

In serial use this `(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: I added the annotations on entity,but still not able to auto increment the values of id.Also,the second solution is not possible for me,as the structure of table is already defined.

Comment: After restarting my server,it works fine now.Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome, please tell me what actuate changes you made?

Comment: I was actually using
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  whereas datatype of id was Long,instead of serial.I used AUTO in place of IDENTITY.

Comment: (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

According to comments changing datatype to `serial`isn't an option. In that case you have to calculate new id each time. Simple way like this

```
INSERT INTO post (id, message)
(SELECT MAX(id)+1, ' <message here> ' FROM post);
```

And better way is use sequence for ID. But if you cannot create anything in schema, then you cannot use it.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: I think when you use serial, it internally creates a sequence and manages it.

Comment: Yes, serial is just a shortcut for certain type of sequence.